# Referring to someone using their current title when discussing them in a past context

Tags: word-usage

Do I refer to a currently knighted individual as *Sir* when discussing them in a past context (before they were knighted)?

This has never occurred to me until I had to specifically discuss usage and I wondered if any convention exists.

Comment: The then Mr Lancelot.

Comment: @edwin-ashworth I agree, doing this works perfectly well of course, but only in context - I ask my question in a more general sense and this solution only really works prefixed with some kind of reference to the current title. In isolation saying _The then…_ doesn’t really mean much - he could be a Dr. for all we know.

Comment: Unless you want to make a point of the fact that the event occurred before they received the title, I don't think any special language is needed. You can say "Sir John Gielgud was born in 1904."

Comment: You can say something like "Prior to his knighthood ..." or "pre-doctor"

Comment: Sir Lancelot, when he was just a squire n years ago, past-tense-verbed.

Comment: "When President Washington was a child he cut down a cherry tree." That's commonly used, but clearly Washington didn't have the title President when he was a child.

Comment: The title of your question is much broader than the body of your question. Can you clarify your intent? Are you specifically asking about "Sir", or are you asking about such titles *in general*, with "Sir" merely being an example?

Answer (score 1):

I would use some variant of the 'the then (title at the time)', like 'the then Mr Lancelot', or 'the future (title now)', like 'the future Sir Lancelot', to imply the title is not being used at the time of the events.

Otherwise use the title in conjunction with a specific time, i.e. When Sir Lancelot was six, he ... With the or year providing the context for readers to assume the title was not yet awarded.